# Rewrite URL with multiple unset query parameters .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have read lots of questions regarding URL rewriting with multiple parameters. However I still cannot fix this issue:

I have this URL with multiple parameters, some of them without a value
  `http://localhost:8888/coches/index.php?maker=all&model=&registration_year=&price_until=&tfseekfid=main_search&s=~`

I would like to rewrite it to `http://localhost:8888/coches/all-cars`

I have tried this rule and several other ones but can´t get it to work.

```
RewriteRule ^all-cars$ /index.php?maker=all&model=&registration_year=&price_until=&tfseekfid=main_search&s=~ [L,QSA]
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Location of the `.htaccess` file containing this rule is important. You can have `.htaccess` files in sub-directories.

If the `.htaccess` file is in your docroot you need to specify the directory in your rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^coches/all-cars$ /coches/index.php?maker=all&model=&registration_year=&price_until=&tfseekfid=main_search&s=~ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If the file is `/coches/.htaccess`, remove the leading `/` from your rule to make it relative to the sub-directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^all-cars$ index.php?maker=all&model=&registration_year=&price_until=&tfseekfid=main_search&s=~ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My path is /coches/.htaccess
I have tried both of your suggestions and none of them worked unfortunately

Comment: @Santos, do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in Apache?

Comment: Yes, Apache rewrite is enabled

Comment: @Santos, and do you have `AllowOverride All` configured for your local environment?

Comment: This is my MAMP Apache httpd.conf file

`<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>` @labue
This is the content of my .htaccess file, I am using wordpress, in case it makes any difference. 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /coches/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /coches/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^tipo/(.*) vehicle_type/$1

</IfModule>